# Could not find goal 'build-image' in plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I am trying to build a image from my spring-boot project.

This is my configuration for spring-boot maven plugin:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>abc/xyz-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                    <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But while building the image "spring-boot:build-image" from Eclipse to build a image giving me following error:

> Could not find goal 'build-image' in plugin
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE among
> available goals build-info, help, repackage, run, start, stop -> [Help
> 1]

Not sure what exactly the issue is.

Thanks,

Atul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and also able to solved it.
The configuration needed :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>abc/xyz-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                    <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Need to specify the version of sring-boot here. **2.4.2**

Recently I was moved to version 2.4.2 spring boot version.

Thanks,

Atul

Answer (score 0):

You need Spring Boot version 2.3.0.M1 or higher. The solution provided by @Atul above uses 2.4.2 so its a later version and has this feature.

[For more information check this link](https://spring.io/blog/2020/01/27/creating-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3-0-m1)